# Deep link to app or navigate to another page when app not installed

Tags: web, deep-linking

We have a mobile application (both IOS and Android), and we're building a website that to mimic the functionality of the mobile app. The problem I'm facing is, when the user clicks on an item in website, I want the following:

- if user installed app: use deep links to mobile app
- if user has not installed app: navigate to another page (basically stay on our website, and navigate to another page)

I can achieve each of them individually, but I cannot find a way to determine whether user installed app or not.

Answer (score 0):

With a deep linking solution you can create links that will do exactly that.
In iOS Universal links, and in Android - App Links.

For example, if your website is *[www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com)*, you can create Universal links for *[www.myapp.com/product1](http://www.myapp.com/product1)*.
If the app is installed, the app will open and you can route the user to the product1 activity. If the app is not installed, it will go in the web to that page.

You can seem more info in a managed solution, e.g. [AppsFlyer OneLink](https://www.appsflyer.com/zero-budget-marketing) or Branch.io, etc